# How to import all tables with indexes and keys from a DB2 database to SQL Server 2008 using SSIS?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis, db2

I tried import/export wizard to import tables from a DB2 database using OLE DB connections. It worked fine but I am not able to get the indexes, stored procedures, keys. I only can get data. Please let me know if there is a way I can import data along with objects.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best way would be to export the DDL (for instance using the `db2look` command), adapt it to the MS DDL if necessary, create the tables, keys, stored procedures (if possible) and then export and import the data. Stored procedures might not be that easy, since the stored procedure languages are different and even if they are written in Java or something portable, it's probably much more involved.

Comment: I am completely new to DB2. I connected to db2 server thru putty and trying to run the command db2look but I am getting error (i doubt that is the correct method, but just gave it a try). Where can I run the db2look command and get all data saved?

Comment: No that's exactly right, but you have to run it as the right user. Normally it's db2inst. You find documentation of the command here: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0002051.html

Comment: I just have permissions to read and export from DB2. Should I have more permissions to run this?

Comment: error I am getting "DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL30070N  "Unsupported function for SPMDB connect" Command is not supported.
SQLSTATE=58014"

Comment: Sorry, I don't know enough about the command line tool myself. Did you try using the GUI tools? Maybe download Data Studio, which should also have that functionality.